# Collection View freezes for long when populated using response obtained by hitting API

Tags: ios, objective-c, collectionview

I am trying to get data from server and populate collection view cells with that data, but when collection view gets populated freezes and takes very long time to scroll.

What is exactly going wrong?

```
-(void)callService:(NSNumber*)categoryid{
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer
                                  serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [dict setValue:@1 forKey:@"page"];
    [dict setValue:@25 forKey:@"limit"];

  [dict setValue:categoryid forKey:@"category_id"];

    [manager POST:@"https://www.foodfuels.com/Api/getrecipes"
       parameters:dict progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task,id responseObject)
     {
         int status = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"status"] intValue];

         if(status == 200)
         {
             responseArray = [responseObject valueForKey:@"data"];

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:true];
                 [_outerCollectionView reloadData];

             });
         }

         else
         {
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"logininfo"];
             UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"some eror!"  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:Nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
             [alert show];
         }
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

          //[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

         });

     }
          failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error)
     {         
         UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:Nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];

         [alert show];

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           //  [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

         });

     }];

}
```

Collection View

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(collectionView==_headingCollectionView){
        recipeHeading = (RecipeHeadingCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"headingCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        _headingCollectionView.delegate = self;
        [recipeHeading.headingBtn setTitle:[recipeTypeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [recipeHeading.headingBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        bool d = [allValues[indexPath.row] boolValue];

        if(d)
        {
            [recipeHeading.headingBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:36/255.0 green:71/255.0 blue:113/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];            [recipeHeading.headingBtn addSubview:bottomBorder];
        }
        else
        {
            [recipeHeading.headingBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

        return recipeHeading;
    }
    else if (collectionView==_outerCollectionView){
        RecipeOuterCell *outerCell =(RecipeOuterCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"outerCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return outerCell;
    }
    else{
        RecipeInnerCell *innerCell = (RecipeInnerCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"innerCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [innerCell populateRecipeScreen:responseArray index:indexPath];
        return innerCell;

    }
}
```

Inner Collection View Cell

```
-(void)populateRecipeScreen:(NSArray*)recipeResponseArr index:(NSIndexPath*)path{
    NSLog(@"the value of recipe array are as follows %@",recipeResponseArr);
    for(int i=0;i<recipeResponseArr.count;i++){
        self.comment_Count.text =[[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"comment_count"]objectAtIndex:path.row]stringValue];
        self.titleLbl.text =[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"description"]objectAtIndex:path.row];
        self.like_Count.text = [[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"like_count"]objectAtIndex:path.row]stringValue];
        NSData *data= [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"user"]valueForKey:@"image"]  objectAtIndex:path.row]]];
        ;            self.smallImgView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

        self.share_Count.text = [[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"share_count"]objectAtIndex:path.row]stringValue];
        self.subTitleLbl.text = [[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"user"]valueForKey:@"username"]  objectAtIndex:path.row];
        NSLog(@"url obtained as result %@",[[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"upload_images"]valueForKey:@"name"]  objectAtIndex:path.row]);
        NSArray *urlString = [[[recipeResponseArr valueForKey:@"upload_images"]valueForKey:@"name"]  objectAtIndex:path.row];

        NSData *mainData=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString objectAtIndex:0]]];
        self.mainImg.image=[UIImage imageWithData:mainData];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are loading images from network (namely from `recipeResponseArr["user"]["image"]` in main thread via [initWithContentsOfURL:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-initwithcontentsofurl). This is strongly discouraged and against best practised. From the documentation:

> Important
>
> Don't use this synchronous method to request network-based URLs. For
>   network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens
>   of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and
>   in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated.
>
> Instead, for non-file URLs, consider using the
>   dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler: method of the NSURLSession class.
>   See URL Session Programming Guide for details.

If you need effective and easy tool to load images I would recommend using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage)